# How to verify None-Mocked methods are called in c# XUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

```
    public async Task<bool> Handle(ConfirmPlayerCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var player = await _context.Players.FirstAsync(a => a.Id == request.PlayerId, cancellationToken);
        player.ConfirmPlayer();
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        return true;
    }
```

z
I have this code in my CommandHandler. I know how to verify if **_context.SaveChangesAsync** is called by using **Moq**.
The problem is, I don't know how to make sure that **player.ConfirmPlayer();** is called.

The **Player.ConfirmPlayer()** should be called to make the player confirmed.
The palyer object is not injected so it is not mocked either.
I expect a way to write a test that checks **Player.ConfirmPlayer()** is called.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a side effect from calling `player.ConfirmPLayer();`. Either the player object changes so you can inspect that, or it calls something else which you can inspect/verify.

We know nothing about how you setup your tests or fixtures, so we cannot really help you if your error is related to that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at last.
As the **Player** object is not injected directly, there is no way to verify it directly.
Yet a trick would help here:
You can create a player mock and let the DBset returns it:

```
[Fact]
public void Handle_CommandIsValid_PlayerConfirmIsCalled()
{
    var _playerMock = new Mock<Player>("name", "my@email.com",             
        "password", Role.SimplePlayer);
    _playerMock!.SetupGet(a=>a.Id).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
    _contextMock!.Setup(a => a.Players)
        .ReturnsDbSet((new List<Player>() 
            {_playerMock.Object}).AsQueryable());

    Handler!.Handle(Command!, new CancellationToken());

    _playerMock!
        .Verify(x=>x.ConfirmPlayer(),Times.Once);
}
```